# Find vowels in string not working

Tags: c++, string

My program checks if an input string contains vowels. In case no vowels were found, it prints "not found".

```
string stringInput;
cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
cin >> stringInput;
if ((stringInput.find('a')) || (stringInput.find('e')) || (stringInput.find('i')) || 
    (stringInput.find('o')) || (stringInput.find('u')) != string::npos)
{
    cout << "not found";
}
else
{
    cout << "found";
}
```

Regardless of the input, everytime I run the program, it prints "not found".

Comment: you have to do the != for each .find call

Comment: Hint: Look at the return value of `std::string::find`. I suggest you to look into `std::string::find_first_of`.

Comment: `find` returns the position of the character, not `true` or `false`. It returns `npos` if the value is not found.

Comment: You'd better use `find_first_of`

Comment: In addition to what  Algirdas suggested, also checkout `string::npos`. Also see [What does string::npos mean](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3827926/608639).

Comment: @jww if you scroll to the right, there is `string::npos`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `string::find` does not return `bool`. It returns an iterator the the found element. If the element was not found, it returns `string::npos`. The appropriate way of doing this is checking whether the function returned something else than `string::npos`.

Take a look at this example:

```
std::string Name = "something";
if(Name.find('g') != std::string::npos) std::cout << "Found the letter 'g'!";
else std::cout << "There is no letter 'g' in the string Name.";
```

If you understand the example above, I'm sure you will be able to edit your code and get the expected result.

EDIT: as **Tobi303** mentioned, the problem lies with only one instance of `!= string::npos`. Creating logical statements are `something || something || something` you expect `something` to be a `bool`. In this case, you should compare *EACH* instance of `string::find` with `string::npos`. That would look like this:

```
if((stringInput.find('a')) != std::string::npos || (stringInput.find('e')) != std::string::npos || (stringInput.find('i')) != std::string::npos || (stringInput.find('o')) != std::string::npos || (stringInput.find('u')) != string::npos){//code}
```

Comment: he has the `!= sting::npos`, but only once.

Comment: seems like OP knowns about what `find` returns, but not how to or several conditions

Comment: @tobi303, I edited the answer mentioning your input. I originally thought that OP was expecting `bool` return value from `string::find`. Good catch

Comment: you could add that the iterator returned by find is converted to bool and  only the first condition was ever evaluated in his code

Comment: .. and please add some formatting. The ugly long line caused already enough confusion in OPs code ;)