# Comparison of unsigned int is always true (npos issue?)

Tags: c++, comparison-operators

I’m receiving an error:

```
error: comparison of constant 18446744073709551614 with
     expression of type 'unsigned int' is always true
     [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
```

The line of code it is referring to is this:

```
if (key_index != std::string::npos)
```

`key_index` is an `unsigned int` local variable in my `main()` function that my `if` statement is also in.

I read through a few posts on here already, trying to make sense of where I’m going wrong.

This link was the most informative

[What does string::npos mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827926/)

But, even utilizing the advice from there, I’m still coming up with the same errors.

I’ve tried to create my own variable:

```
const int NPOS = -1
```

I’ve modified the comparison operator a few different ways.

I’ve tried turning the line into:

```
if(key_index != (std::string::npos -1))
```

I’ve tried a few other minor changes, which I cannot recall at the moment.

I forgot to write them down, and I apologize for not having all of my test/mod details.

This is the full `main()` code the issue is coming from. For all I know, there might be something else that I need to correct instead.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <math.h>  // For pow()
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>  // For std::runtime_error
#include <vector>
#include "GuitarString.hpp"

const sf::Uint32 quit_key = 27;       // ASCII 27 is the Escape key

const std::string keyboard = "q2we4r5ty7u8i9op-[=zxdcfvgbnjmk,.;/' ";
const int num_keys = keyboard.length();
const int kDuration = 8;

std::vector<sf::Int16> makeSamplesFromString(GuitarString *gs) {
    std::vector<sf::Int16> samples;

    gs->pluck();
    for (int i= 0; i < kSampleRate * kDuration; i++) {
        gs->tic();
        samples.push_back(gs->sample());
    }

    return samples;
}

int main() {
    sf::Event event;
    double frequency;    
    unsigned int key_index; 

    std::vector < std::vector<sf::Int16> > samples(num_keys);

    std::vector<sf::SoundBuffer> buffers(num_keys);

    std::vector<sf::Sound> sounds(num_keys);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_keys; ++i) {
        frequency = 440 * pow(2, (i-24) / 12.0L);
        GuitarString gs = GuitarString(frequency);

        samples[i] = makeSamplesFromString(&gs);

        if (!buffers[i].loadFromSamples(&samples[i][0],
                                    samples[i].size(), 2, kSampleRate)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("sf::SoundBuffer: failed to load from samples.");
        }

        sounds[i].setBuffer(buffers[i]);
    }

    sf::Vector2u size_win(500, 200);
    sf::Sprite background_sprite;       
    sf::Texture background_texture;
    if (background_texture.loadFromFile("keyboard.png")) {
        background_sprite.setTexture(background_texture);
        size_win = background_texture.getSize();
    }

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(size_win.x, size_win.y),
                          " PS5B GuitarHero - Press Escape to Exit ");

    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                    key_index = keyboard.find(event.text.unicode);
                    if (key_index != std::string::npos) { // the line causing the issue….
                        sounds[key_index].play();
                    } else if (event.text.unicode == quit_key) {
                        window.close();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(background_sprite);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could trim your sample code down to less than 10 lines and still illustrate the problem. Did you copy the error message correctly? I'd expect `npos` to be `18446744073709551615`, not `18446744073709551614`.

Comment: `std::string::npos` is unsigned and contains the largest possible unsigned value.  If `key_index` is a signed type or a small type than (the type of) `std::string::npos` then the not-equal comparison must always be true

Comment: Oh, I see what happened. You modified the program, changing the test to `(key_index != (std::string::npos -1))`, and showed us the error message from the modified version, but the code in the question is still the original.

Comment: Hi Keith ~ You are right! I'm super sorry about that. Aside from the missing digit, the error message comes up the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on a 64bit system, `std::string::npos` is almost certainly a 64bit number.  To ensure maximum portability, use the type specified by `std::string`.

```
std::string::size_type key_index;
```

That should work, regardless of whether you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Comment: Regardless of whether you are on a 32bit or 64bit system, `std::string::find()` returns a `std::string::size_type`, and also `std::string::npos` is declared as a `std::string::size_type`, so you should be using `std::string::size_type` to save the return value without risking data loss, and to perform comparisons against `npos` and other string indexes.

Comment: Thank you both Remy and Stephen! Modifying my key_index variable to align with std::string::npos was the missing link I hadn't read anywhere, so I kept trying to force it as the unsigned int into the std::string.