# C++ Strings: size_t and string::npos

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to understand this piece if code and how it works...

So here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  //C++ Strings Library
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s1 {};
  string wordFind {};
  s1 = "The secret word is Boo";
    cout << "Enter the word to find: ";
    cin >> wordFind;
    size_t position = s1.find(wordFind);
     if (position != string::npos)
        cout << "Found " << wordFind << " at position: " << position << endl;
     else
        cout << "Sorry! " << wordFind << " not found" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

These are the questions that I actually have:

1. What is `size_t` and when should we use them exactly?(All I know is that we should use them for array indexing and loop counting)
2. Why did we use `size_t` here? couldn't it be like this?:

`position = s1.find(wordFind);`

3. What is position exactly?(I mean is it made up or is it a part of C++?)
4. Does the if condition mean to search the word untill the end of the string?

Edit:Thank you everyone for helping me...I appreciate it:)

Comment: `position = s1.find(wordFind);` lacks a type for the variable `position`. I don't know what you mean with "*is it made up or is it a part of C++?*". Regarding `size_t` see e.g. [What's the difference between size_t and int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-size-t-and-int-in-c). Regarding the `if` condition see [What does string::npos mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827926/what-does-stringnpos-mean).

Comment: I think U should read some c++ book because you need to know somethings can't be included in one answer

Comment: @anonymous yeah you're right...I definitely should...right now I'm learning from a udemy course made by Frank mitropoulos and also internet :))

Comment: @walnut Ok...I explain... 1. by made up I mean is it like naming a variable by ourselves or is it like a keyword here(for example: int num1 {}; I gave num1 ny myself)    2.what I don't understand from size_t is this: does it return the size of the object in byte?

Comment: @DavidPeterson `size_t` is just a type like e.g. `int` and `position` is just an arbitrary variable name. I second the recommendation to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). All of this should have been made clear in an introductory course or book.

Comment: `size_t` should be used when 1. You want something to represent an index and you're not doing any arithmetic on it or 2. You want it to work with values outside of the range of `int`. Otherwise use `int` as default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is `size_t` and when should we use them exactly?(All I know is that we should use them for array indexing and loop counting)

`size_t` is an unsigned integer type large enough to represent the size of any object in C++, including array types. (size as in how much memory it occupies in bytes).

> Why did we use `size_t` here?

Because it is typically large enough, and using something like `int` wouldn't be enough if the string is larger than the maximum number `int` can store. Pedantically, you should have used `std::string::size_type`, which is guaranteed to be capable of holding the size of a `std::string`, no matter how large it is.

> couldn't it be like this?: `position = s1.find(wordFind);`

No, you have to specify the type of `position`. Alternatively you can use `auto`: `auto position = s1.find(wordFind);`

> What is position exactly?(I mean is it made up or is it a part of C++?)

Just a variable representing the index of the substring (word) you are searching for.

> Does the if condition mean to search the word untill the end of the string?

It's checking to see if the word is found. `std::string::npos` is a special number `std::string::find` returns when the sought substring is not found.

Comment: Thank you...one thing though...did we name it "position" by ourselves or does it have to exactly be position?

Comment: @DavidPeterson you could name it anything you want. It's not a special name

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by saying that IMHO, `std::string` is kind of a lame string class design, or at least - certainly shows its age, in several ways.

> 1. What is `size_t` and when should we use it exactly?

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is `std::size_t` (in C++ it's *not* simply `size_t`). But let's not talk about when exactly when you should use it, because...

> 2. Why did we use `size_t` here?

I'd say we should not have. We should either have written

```
auto position = s1.find(wordFind);
```

(like you actually suggested, but with `auto` to indicate automatic type deduction),
or if we want to be explicit, then:

```
std::string::size_type position = s1.find(wordFind);
```

Because that's what `find()` returns. It often *happens* to be `std::size_t`, but: (a) Maybe not, I'm not even sure (thanks @Ayxan); (b) you shouldn't care about whether it's `std::size_t` or not, usually.

But even the above options are not right. There's a deeper problem here - and the problem is that `find()` should really return an `[std::optional][2]<std::string::size_type>`. Except that C++ didn't have an optional type until recently, so the string class kind of jerry-rigged it. A failure to find a substring returns a value consecrated as inherently invalid: `std::string::npos` (which has type `std::string::size_type`). So perhaps what we *should* have written is:

```
auto to_optional = [](std::string::size_type pos_or_npos) { 
   return pos_or_npos == std::string::npos ? 
       std::nullopt : 
       std::optional<std::string::size_type>{pos_or_npos};
};
auto position = to_optional(s1.find(wordFind));
```

Which is more like what we actually mean: Either you got some position, or you didn't.

> 3. What is position exactly?(I mean is it made up or is it a part of C++?)

See my last paragraph.

> 4. Does the if condition mean to search the word until the end of the string?

No, the `find()` already searches until the end. With our recasting, the `if()` would look like:

```
if (position.has_value()) 
// ... etc etc
else
// ... etc etc
```

Comment: "It happens to be std::size_t" Not necessarily. It doesn't have to be `std::size_t`

Comment: @Ayxan: Thanks for your comments, edited. I write `typename` defensively; we don't need it because `std::string` is a concrete type, not a template, right? (Although IIRC in C++20 we wouldn't need it anyway).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because it's a concrete type.