# what is npos ??? My problem is I do not understand why anyone would use it

Tags: c++

What is npos ??? I recently saw it in some source code and really want to know what it is used for and why it is used. An example would be nice also. Thanks(:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does string::npos mean in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827926/what-does-stringnpos-mean-in-this-code)

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos.

Comment: @chiefus If you wrote that "I recently saw it in some source code" then you already have an example.

Comment: Ya @Moscow but the example is too complicated for me just want a more basic one.

Comment: You could look for documentation on the function that was being used in that code. For example, look at the return value of [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says :

> npos is a static member constant value with the greatest possible
>   value for an element of type size_t
>
> This value, when used as the value for a len (or sublen) parameter
>   in string's member functions, means "until the end of the string".
>
> As a return value, it is usually used to indicate no matches.

It is defined internally as :

```
static const size_t npos = -1;
```

Just remember, it's used to indicate not found.